# Maui RC1 - "System.NotSupportedException: Must call AddTerm AddSeparator in that order"

Tags: c#, image, maui

I installed the last update for Maui (https://github.com/dotnet/maui).
When I add an image, it makes an error:
"error MAUI0000: System.NotSupportedException: Must call AddTerm AddSeparator in that order"

This is easy to reproduce:

1. Update your VS2022 to the last update.
2. Create a Maui Mobile
3. Add Image to the "Resources/Images"
4. Put it the kind to "MauiImage"
5. Try to compile.

Edit: Go Release instead of Debug and it works.
Edit: Nah, it took cache and if the solution is cleaned, it break again with the same error.
Edit: It's when you want to change "appicon.svg"

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "When I add an image" - if you could show your XAML or C#, that would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is easy to reproduce:
1/ Update your VS2022 to the last update.
2/ Create a Maui Mobile project
3/ Add Image to the "Resources/Images"
4/ Put it in "MauiImage"
5/ Try to compile.